# How to Programmatically Detect Previous Active Instances and Workspace Locations in Eclipse RCP Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP (Rich Client Platform) application, and I typically launch multiple instances of this application via an executable. Each time I launch a new instance, I need to detect the currently active instances and determine their respective workspace locations programmatically.

I believe this functionality should be implemented in the IAppliaction #start method. However, I'm unsure about how to find the previous active instances and retrieve their workspace locations in my Eclipse RCP application.

If you have experience with Eclipse RCP or can provide guidance on how to achieve this programmatically, I would greatly appreciate your help. Please share any code snippets, insights, or suggestions on how to detect and retrieve information about previous active instances and their associated workspace locations in Eclipse RCP. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: There isn't anything that records active instances. You would have to maintain that somewhere.